# Static route to uploaded files

Tags: haskell, yesod

I need to access a file in the static folder of Yesod, which gets uploaded there at runtime, so it does not have an identifier.
Is there any way to construct a static route to such file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the StaticRoute constructor directly, along the lines of:

```
StaticRoute ["somefile.txt"] []
```